# What is Lightroom's keyboard shortcut for changing color temperature?

Tags: lightroom, keyboard-shortcuts

In the Develop module of Adobe Lightroom you can change the white balance tint slider with the `+` and `-` keys. This is **not** mentioned on the [official keyboard shortcut guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/keyboard-shortcuts.html). Are there also keyboard shortcuts that control the color temperature? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the word "Temp" and then use the + or - keys. This works for any slider. You'll see the info notification over the image when you click.

Comment: Thanks so much! This also explains why I thought these keys were undocumented.